# Как "привязать" popup menu к определенным координатам View?

Tags: java, android

Есть слушатель, чтобы определить место касания (где хочу вывести меню):

```
ivScr0.setOnPhotoTapListener(new OnPhotoTapListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPhotoTap(ImageView view, float _x, float _y) { 
       ShowMenuChangeDate(_x,_y, view); }
    });
```

Создаю меню так:

```
public void ShowMenuChangeDate(int x, int y, View view) {
    final PopupMenu mChData = new PopupMenu(this, view);
    mChData.getMenu().add(0, 0, 0, getString(R.string.tCh0));
    mChData.getMenu().add(0, 1, 0, getString(R.string.tCr3));
    mChData.getMenu().add(0, 2, 0, getString(R.string.tTr2));
    mChData.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case 0: mInp(c1, false); return true;
                case 1: mInp(c2, false); return true;
                case 2: mInp(c3, false);  return true;
                default: return false;
            }
        }
    });
    mChData.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {  } 
    });
    mChData.show();
}
```

Как воспользоваться координатами места касания PhotoView ivScr0, чтобы вывести меню в месте касания?